# How to know the type of the cell returned by getValueAt()?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I know that it returns type Object, is there a way to change the type to the most suitable one? For example, it looks at the cell, if it is a float, it changes to float, a string changes to type string and so on.

***EDIT***

Okay, the cell is in a jtable, I am trying to make a ranged filter, the user enters two numbers to filter a column that keeps the ones only within the range.

I tried casting `if( (Float) table.getvalueat(i,j) > Float.valueOf(textfield.getText()) )` which works, but sometimes the values in the table are `long` and returns an error during runtime.

Comment: what type of cell? where do you get it from? what have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, `TableModel#getColumnClass(int)` return type of column.

Comment: @Stultuske I have edited my question.

Comment: @mrmcwolf I see, what if i want to compare it to textfield.getText()? Since that returns a string, how can I make it the same type of class as getValueAT()? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
if(value instanceof float)
```

Or

```
if(value instanceof long)
```

Answer (score 1):

All objects in java are the heirs of `Object`. Which means instead of `Object` you can return everything you want.

```
public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel implements TableModel {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0: return Integer.class;
            case 1: return Double.class;
            case 2: return Boolean.class;
            case 3: return Date.class;
            case 4: return String.class;
        }

        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0: return 1;
            case 1: return 1.2;
            case 2: return true;
            case 3: return new Date();
            case 4: return "My Text Value";
        }

        return new Object();
    }
}
```

If you are using Object virtual methods (like equals) you can target objects directly:

```
textfield.getText().equals(model.getValueAt(1, 4));
```

For more specific things, you'll need to make an explicit cast to the appropriate type (which returns `TableMOdel#getColumnClass(int)`).

**update** :
In the model, you can add a template method that saves your explicit casting in value retrieval.

```
public <T> T getValue(int row, int column) {
    return (T) getValueAt(row, column);
}
```

You will then be able to use the cell value as follows:

```
Integer var0 = model.getValue(1, 0);
Double var1 = model.getValue(1, 1);
Boolean var2 = model.getValue(1, 2);
Date var3 = model.getValue(1, 3);
String var4 = model.getValue(1, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! Works perfectly fine now :)